# Find conjunctive normal form of propositional formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I need to find conjunctive normal form (CNF) of this propositional formula:

$$\lnot((p \implies (q \implies r)) \implies ((p \implies \lnot r) \implies (p \implies \lnot q)))$$

How could i do that? I got stuck at this point:
\begin{align}
&\quad \lnot((p \implies (q \implies r)) \implies ((p \implies \lnot r) \implies (p \implies \lnot q))) \\
&= (p \implies (q \implies r)) \land \lnot((p \implies \lnot r) \implies (p \implies \lnot q)) \\
&= (p \implies (q \implies r)) \land ((p \implies \lnot r) \land \lnot (p \implies \lnot q)) \\
&= ((p \land q) \implies r)) \land ((p \implies \lnot r) \land (p \land q)) \\
&= ((\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor r)) \land ((\lnot p \lor \lnot r) \land (p \land q))
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\quad \lnot((p \implies (q \implies r)) \implies ((p \implies \lnot r) \implies (p \implies \lnot q))) \\
&\equiv \lnot(\lnot(\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor r)) \lor (\lnot(\lnot p \lor \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor \lnot q))) \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor r)) \land \lnot (\lnot(\lnot p \lor \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)) \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land ((\lnot p \lor \lnot r) \land \lnot (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)) \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot r) \land p \land q \\
\end{align}
Looks like you just have an error in the last line.
This is already in CNF, but by distributing $\land$ over $\lor$ you can further reduce to identically false.